# month() function and year() function in postgresql through jpa2

Tags: postgresql, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

How to get the month and year of a postgresql date field using jpa2 criteria query or jpql?

Has anybody done this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `FUNC('MyFunc', a, b, c)`

Example: `SELECT FUNC('to_char', current_date, 'month')`

Answer (score 1):

With JPA criteria API (tested only with Hibernate) :

```
// Create expressions that extract date parts:
Expression<Integer> year = cb.function("year", Integer.class, date);
Expression<Integer> month = cb.function("month", Integer.class, date);
Expression<Integer> day = cb.function("day", Integer.class, ts);

// Create expressions that extract time parts:
Expression<Integer> hour = cb.function("hour", Integer.class, time);
Expression<Integer> minute = cb.function("minute", Integer.class, time);
Expression<Integer> second = cb.function("second", Integer.class, ts);
```

Source : http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date#Date_and_Time_in_Criteria_Queries_

With jpql (tested only with Hibernate) :

```
YEAR(date)
MONTH(date)
DAY(date) 
HOUR(date)
MINUTE(date)
SECOND(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few examples, how to extract the month from a date or timestamp in PostgreSQL:

```
select to_char(now(), 'month');
select to_char(now(), 'MM');
select extract('month' from now());
select date_part('month', now());
```

Just [read the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: how to do criteria query JPA of JEE6