# Syntax error in date_part function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I have syntax error in following query which retrieve month from `last_updated_time` column from `BIZ_TRANSACTION` where `last_updated_time` stored as millisecond. So, how can I apply `date_part()` function?
I used the following query but it shows syntax error near `date_part()`.

```
SELECT date_part('month', timestamp TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(LAST_UPDATED_TIME / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
FROM BIZ_TRANSACTION
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775187/month-function-and-year-function-in-postgresql-through-jpa2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like that:

```
SELECT date_part('month',to_timestamp(LAST_UPDATED_TIME/1000));
FROM BIZ_TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

[`DATE_PART`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function requries two arguments of type text and some type of time/date/interval respectively.

When you convert your timestamp to a char type there is no function which matches your input types as it becomes text and text.

Also, this is a superfluous overhead to cast the timestamp to char when you retrieve the month number from it. Formatting doesn't make any difference in that case and it is better to work on Postgres default datestyles so that you won't encounter errors you have just encountered :-)

```
select date_part('month', to_timestamp(last_updated_time/1000))
from biz_transaction
```

List of `date_part` functions for 9.5 version is (see for yourself in psql by typing `\df date_part`):

```
  Schema   |    Name    |  Result datatype  |        Datatype of arguments
------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------------
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, abstime                     
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, date                        
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, interval                    
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, reltime                     
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, time with time zone         
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, time without time zone      
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, timestamp with time zone    
 pg_catalog | date_part | double precision  | text, timestamp without time zone
```